# float object not attribute of str error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling

one of my columns in my dataframe is IC no. (below), which is the country identification card number of the member. I am trying to create another column to sniff out those with 'S' infront using function and apply method. But I got the error message below. Can someone point out the problem? Thanks!

[image]

```
def f(x):
        if x['IC No_'].str.startswith('S',na=False): return 1
        else : return 0
MbrKPI['Sing']=MbrKPI.apply(f,axis=1)
```

> AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Instead of `x['IC No_'].str`, maybe you meant `str(x['IC No_'])`?

Comment: that needs to be `str(x['IC No_']).startswith`

Comment: tried the above, it returned error TypeError: ('startswith() takes no keyword arguments', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: `str(x['IC No_']).startswith('S')` should take care of even `NaN` as they would be converted to strings. Alternatively, a one-line syntax would be: `MbrKPI['IC No_'].str.startswith('S', na=False).astype(int)`.

Comment: i removed na=False, it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
if str(x['IC No_']).startswith('S'): return 1
```